# Cannot log on to a remote server using rdp from windows 7 machine when I am remotley connected to that machine from Mac (OS 10.6)

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, mac-osx, remote-desktop, terminal-server

Bear withe me, here is my set up.

I use my 27" iMac 3.06GHz Core 2 Duo 4GB Ram to connect to my work desktop running Windows 7.
From there I can administer other remote servers.

Here is the problem. Using the Remote Desktop Client on my Mac I can connect to my work machine no problem. But when I then use the work machine to open a remote desktop session with another Windows server (usually SBS 2003 but applies to all) I get the log in prompt, I enter the user name password ensure i'm connecting to the domain, but it wont log me in. The error message is the same, as though I had typed the wrong password (i know this is not the case). Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Gary

Comment: Additional info, i can make the remote connections if I am sitting at my work machine, in fact thats the work around, I phone a colleague get them to set up the rdp from my machine to the remote server, then I connect from my Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing would be to check the event viewer on the server when this is not working to see what it's logging about the connection which doesn't work.  This will help a lot in getting you a complete accurate answer.

In the mean time though, try connecting to the Console session on your work machine, then connecting to the server.  Also if you're using OS X and administering Windows machines you should really do your self a favor and check out CoRD for RDP access - http://cord.sourceforge.net/ - it's the best solution I've found for doing this.  It's really nice to have all of you're connections saved so all you have to do is click on one.  Check it out, you won't regret it...

Comment: Thanks for that. CoRD has done the trick. I would still like to get to the bottom of the the problem, but given CoRD is working, I am not going to waste too much energy on this. 

Thanks again -- Gary